# Why is the population so high in Kali yuga?

Tags: karma, kali-yuga

It is said that one gets the human form after collecting a lot of good karma, then how the population has increased to such? As it is Kali yuga and good is very scanty and will go down even further as time goes by, number of human beings should be decreasing day by day.

Comment: here is an analogy for this inspired by the Great Swami Vivekanandaji (this is just a positive-view of looking at things). You go to the gym. In the gym everything is difficult. You have to lift weights, you have to run on the treadmill, you have to actually work hard! But still you go, why? It is because by toiling hard at the gym, it provides great opportunity to grow. Similarly Kali Yuga is the best time to be born, because it is like a giant gym. Everything is difficult, if you can be good now, then you are the best of men! That's why many souls take birth in Kali Yuga.

Comment: Actually many bhakti-yogis also say that this is the best yuga, because in this yuga chanting of God's names alone is quite enough to take one across the ocean of Bhavasagar. (Although this is easier said). Also for really pious souls who have attained the realm of Divinity Itself, for them this is the best age, Kali Yuga, people are falling off their Dharma, this is the time they need Help. Thus great saints take birth in hundreds in this age to help those souls which are in need of spiritual rescue. God is equally present in all yugas These are the many many positives of Kali Yuga !!!!

Comment: I see that you are trying to show me the brighter side but that does not answer the question. If human form is so difficult to get then how come everybody is getting a human form and human beings are increasing day by day, does that mean all these people who are born were great souls in the past lives and that's how they got human form, otherwise they could have become any other creature.

Comment: Yeah I see your point, but isn't Kalyuga destined to be like this, bad and all sorts of evil will prevail, that's how it's described then why all this help from these saints you are talking about.

Comment: Ah I see your question now, anyway pointing out some positives. If you live your life now and you do some good deeds, then some bad deeds, it does not mean you are immediately born as a beast! After doing some good deeds, the soul gets born as a human. That does not mean that after doing a single bad deed, it becomes a beast again. Many souls in Kali Yuga are pious-enough (although you cannot call them perfect) to be reborn as human beings. Yes war exists, yes killing is more than before, but not everyone descends to such extremes!! This is just one view I am sure there are many others

Comment: as for why saints descend even though they know it is destiny of Kali Yuga. Well that is what is called Love/Compassion/Mercy and that is why these souls are called merciful or having lot of love for us. If one loves his friend, then he will be there for him, even if he knows that the friend is getting what he is destined to get. We are suffering, whether because of destiny or not. The saints still come down for us, they can hear our call. That is their destiny you can say. That is their mission, to share with us the same elixir that they have drank from the True Self or God!

Comment: Even with human form, you can be physically or mentally handicapped which is as bad as becoming an animal or a bird or an insect or a fish... Also, not being born is the best thing if you are in Indra's kingdom with the GODs.

Comment: High population is not only in Kali Yuga, it can be in other yugas also. Kali Yuga had less population compared to the present age of Dwapara.

Comment: Related [souls and population](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8346/277) also see last line at http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8443/277.

Answer (score 3):

**Who gets human form on this earth?**

Generally, the cases are:

1. Some one could be evolving upwards from lower species of life.
2. Some one may have fallen from higher planets after enjoying the results of good
   karma as stated in the Gita verse below.

> When they have thus enjoyed vast heavenly sense pleasure and the
> results of their pious activities are exhausted, they return to this
> mortal planet again. [Bhagvad Gita 9.21](http://www.vedabase.com/bg/9/21)

So we cannot assume that population must decrease in Kali yuga. There is exit and entry going on continously.

Also kali-yuga is not all bad for those interested in self realization. According to [Srimad Bhavatam 1.17.38](http://www.vedabase.com/sb/1/17/38) and [1.17.39](http://www.vedabase.com/sb/1/17/39) influence of Kali is there only in places where gambling, drinking, prostitution, animal slaughter and accumulation of gold (for material enjoyment) is there.

The process of self-realization in kali yuga is also very easy. Just by chanting the holy names of Krishna one can attain perfection. This is confirmed in [Srimad Bhagavatam 12.3.51](http://www.vedabase.com/sb/12/3/51)

> kaler dosa-nidhe rajann
>
> asti hy eko mahan gunah
>
> kirtanad eva krsnasya
>
> mukta-sangah param vrajet
>
> My dear King, although Kali-yuga is an ocean of faults, there is still
> one good quality about this age: Simply by chanting the Hare Krsna
> maha-mantra, one can become free from material bondage and be promoted
> to the transcendental kingdom.

Comment: Do you mean to say the population was as high as kalyuga even in other ages ?

Comment: Is there a reason why it should not? In Dvapara-yuga just Krishna's immediate children + grandchildren were more than 1.6 million.

Answer (score 3):

```
Why the population is so high in Kali-Yuga ?
```

The  answer  to this question is given indirectly in **Shreemad Bhagvat Purana** at various places.I will explain the cause through those Shlokas (verses).Before giving that let me give a brief backgroud about Kaliyuga.

> There is a story of [**King Parikshita & Kaliyuga**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/17/38).In which king
>   parikshita gave four places for kaliyuga to live  they are **1) Gambling**
>   **2) Wine or Alcohol 3) violence 4) Sexual cheating or (Vyabhichara ,
>   व्याभिचार)).** These are the sanskrit verses from Shreemad Bhagvat Purana
>   telling us the characteristics of kaliyuga.

**So What exactly is Kaliyuga**-: According to Bhagvatam Kaliyuga means.

> यदा मायानृतं तन्द्रायदा मायानृतं तन्द्रा निद्रा हिंसा विषादनम।
>   शोको मोहो भयं दैन्यं स **कालिस्तामस:** स्मृत ॥30॥
>
> yadā māyānṛtaṁ tandrā nidrā hiṁsā viṣādanam
>  śoka-mohau bhayaṁ
>   dainyam sa **kalis** tāmasaḥ smṛtaḥ
>
> **Meaning** - When there is a predominance of cheating, lying, sloth, sleepiness, violence, depression, lamentation, bewilderment, fear and
>   poverty, that age is **Kali, the age of the mode of ignorance**.
>
> [**SB 12.3.30**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/3/30)

**characteristics of this Kaliyuga**

> दस्यूत्कृष्टा जनपदा वेदा: पाखण्डदूषिता:।
>  राजनश्च प्रजाभक्षा:
>   **शिश्नोदपरा** द्विजा:॥32॥
>
> dasyūtkṛṣṭā janapadā vedāḥ pāṣaṇḍa-dūṣitāḥ
>  rājānaś ca
>   prajā-bhakṣāḥ **śiśnodara-parā** dvijāḥ
>
> **Meaning** - Cities will be dominated by thieves, the Vedas will be
>   contaminated by speculative interpretations of atheists, political
>   leaders will virtually consume the citizens, and the so-called priests
>   and **intellectuals will be devotees of their bellies and genitals.**
>
> [**SB 12.3.32**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/3/32)
>
> पितृभ्रातृसुहॄज्ज्ञातीन हित्वा सौरतसौह्यदा:।
>  ननान्द्रुश्यालसंवादा
>   दीना: स्त्रैणा: कलौ नरा:॥37॥
>
> pitṛ-bhrātṛ-suhṛj-jñātīn hitvā saurata-sauhṛdāḥ
>   nanāndṛ-śyāla-saṁvādā dīnāḥ straiṇāḥ kalau narāḥ
>
> **Meaning**- In Kali-yuga men will be wretched and controlled by women. They will reject their fathers, brothers, other relatives and
>   friends and will instead associate with the sisters and brothers of
>   their wives. **Thus their conception of friendship will be based
>   exclusively on sexual ties.**
>
> [**SB 12.3.37**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/3/37)
>
> न रक्षिष्यन्ति मनुजा: स्थविरौ पितरावपि ।
>  पुत्रान सर्वार्थकुशलान
>   क्षुद्रा:शिश्नोदरम्भरा॥42॥
>
> na rakṣiṣyanti manujāḥ sthavirau pitarāv api
>  putrān bhāryāṁ ca
>   kula-jām kṣudrāḥ śiśnodaraṁ-bharāḥ
>
> **Meaning** - Men will no longer protect their elderly parents, their children or their respectable wives. Thoroughly degraded, **they will
>   care only to satisfy their own bellies and genitals.**
>
> [**SB 12.3.42**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/3/42)

**So from above shlokas(verses) we come to know that in Kaliyuga People's mind are corrupted due to excessive materialistic desires.They are   more sexual pleasure oriented. They are only thinking of satisfying there sense's or sexual desires.**

And I think that is one of the **reason** of high **population** in Kaliyuga.

Comment: pushkar your answer is ok but this is about the souls increment problem if souls are not created newly then why population increases very much and if souls in animals are born as humans then humans will also be born as animals but animal population is decreasing at a vast rate, only human population is increasing so what is the reason.This is the question friend

Comment: @sakthi - I think animal population is not decreasing.Yes Animal ,bird , insects  species are getting lost at alarming rate.But since we here on Hinduism SE generally refer population as human population , unless specifically mentioned about other population.So the answer is human centric.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the concept of population control, materialistic competition, abortion, sexual gratification, rape, cheating, divorce, etc. are all normal concepts for Kali Yuga, where people have no respect or inclination or rather that intellect required for spiritual learning and knowledge of the Self.

A detailed analysis of Kali Yuga's symptoms is given in the Srimad Bhagavatam, which is one of the famous Puranas.

> 12.2.3
>
> dāmpatye 'bhirucir hetur
>   māyaiva vyāvahārike
>  
>   strītve puḿstve ca hi ratir
>  
>   vipratve sūtram eva hi
>
> > Men and women will live together merely because of superficial
> >     attraction, and success in business will depend on deceit. Womanliness
> >     and manliness will be judged according to one’s expertise in sex, and
> >     a man will be known as a brahmana just by his wearing a thread.
>
> **EXPLANATION** : Just as human life as a whole has a great and serious
>   purpose -- namely spiritual liberation -- fundamental human
>   institutions such as marriage and child-rearing should also be
>   dedicated to that great objective. Unfortunately, in the present age
>   the satisfaction of the sex impulse has become the overriding, if not
>   the exclusive, reason for marriage.
>
> The sexual impulse, which induces the male and female of almost every
>   species to combine physically, and in higher species also emotionally,
>   is ultimately not a natural urge, because it is based on the unnatural
>   identification of the self with the body. Life itself is a spiritual
>   phenomenon. It is the soul that lives and gives apparent life to the
>   biological machine called the body. Consciousness is the soul's
>   manifest energy, and thus consciousness, awareness itself, is
>   originally an entirely spiritual event. When life, or consciousness,
>   is confined within a biological machine and falsely mistakes itself to
>   be that machine, material existence occurs and sex desire arises.
>
> 12.2.5
>
> anāḍhyataivāsādhutve
>  
>   sādhutve dambha eva tu
>   svīkāra eva codvāhe
>   snānam eva prasādhanam
>
> > A person will be judged unholy if he does not have money, and
> >     hypocrisy will be accepted as virtue. Marriage will be arranged simply
> >     by verbal agreement, and a person will think he is fit to appear in
> >     public if he has merely taken a bath.
>
> 12.2.6
>
> dūre vāry-ayanaḿ tīrthaḿ
>  
>   lāvaṇyaḿ keśa-dhāraṇam
>   udaraḿ-bharatā svārthaḥ
>  
>   satyatve dhārṣṭyam eva hi
>  
>   dākṣyaḿ kuṭumba-bharaṇaḿ
>   yaśo 'rthe dharma-sevanam
>
> > A sacred place will be taken to consist of no more than a reservoir of
> >     water located at a distance, and beauty will be thought to depend on
> >     one’s hairstyle. Filling the belly will become the goal of life, and
> >     one who is audacious will be accepted as truthful. He who can maintain
> >     a family will be regarded as an expert man, and the principles of
> >     religion will be observed only for the sake of reputation.
>
> 12.2.7
>
> evaḿ prajābhir duṣṭābhir
>  
>   ākīrṇe kṣiti-maṇḍale
>   brahma-viṭ-kṣatra-śūdrāṇāḿ
>   yo balī bhavitā nṛpaḥ
>
> > **As the earth thus becomes crowded with a corrupt population, whoever among any of the social classes shows himself to be the strongest will
> >     gain political power.**
>
> 12.2.11
>
> triḿśad viḿśati varṣāṇi
>   paramāyuḥ kalau nṛṇām
>
> > The maximum duration of life for human beings in Kali-yuga will become
> >     fifty years.

So as we see here, texts absolutely prove how gratifying the procreating sense pleasures lead us to absolute blindness about God and the spiritual reality. Hence taking procreation for granted, we find the population high. As a balance, Prakriti also caused their lifespans to decrease vastly from earlier yugas.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like more than the current population existed during Mahabharata:

[Mahabharata 11.26.8](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m11/m11025.htm)

> jīvatāṃ parimāṇajñaḥ sainyānām asi pāṇḍava
>
> hatānāṃ yadi jānīṣe parimāṇaṃ vadasva me
>
> > Vaishampayana said, ‘If, O son of Pandu, thou knowest it, **tell me the
> >     number of those that have fallen in this battle, as also of those that
> >     have escaped with life!’**

[Mahabharata 11.26.9](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m11/m11025.htm)

> daśāyutānām ayutaṃ sahasrāṇi ca viṃśatiḥ
>
> koṭyaḥ ṣaṣṭiś ca ṣaṭ caiva ye 'smin rājamṛdhe hatāḥ
>
> "Yudhishthira answered, ‘**One billion 660 million and 20,000 men have
>   fallen in this battle. Of the heroes that have escaped, the number is
>   240,165**.’

More than 166 crore men have died in Mahabharata. Many men survived. I think they were soldiers.If soldiers were lived in this huge number, then think about the population. So, your question on why population is high in Kali Yuga is likely invalid.

Answer (score 0):

There is an obscure rule of karma:

When a human kills an animal intentionally, it generally gets reborn as a human. If the human is degenerate, he may slip back and be born as what he killed.

An analogous truth can be easily found in the scriptures: when God incarnates, and slays whichever Asura is causing havoc, the Asura is liberated; he attains proximity with God (born in a high loka), and becomes enlightened.

When a human kills an animal, the animal attains human form. This is one of the reasons why it is not good to kill as many animals as we do; too many humans have to be born as a result of that, which upsets the dharma (order) on earth.

But hey, the dharma of kali-yuga is to destroy dharma.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! You should cite sources.

Comment: friends i agree with the animals being born as humans but at the same time humans will also be born as animals but in kali yuga other animals population is decreasing in a great rate there is no constant population itself and about 70 or 80 percent of humans kill animals or eat them by buying. If your saying is ok then by now animal population will atleast 3 times of our population but it is decreasing only.