# Number of Jivatmas according to Vishishtadvaita

Tags: atma, vishishtadvaita, ramanujacharya

According to Advaita, the individual self (Atman) is nothing but Brahman (only one). But due to avidya/maya there are many individual selves (Atmas) appearing.

Now, According to Vishsishtadvaita, individual selves (Jivatmas) are different from each other and actually not the Brahman (only one). And (only one) Brahman dwells in Jivatmas.

And these Jivatmas are eternal i.e Jivatma doesn't emerge and dissolve into Brahman.

Now, I want to know whether the there are infinite number of souls (Jivatmas) or there is finite/fixed number of souls (Jivatmas)?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  No, the number of atmas on Earth isn't constant, because there are also atmas in other worlds.  But if you add the total number of atmas in all the worlds (plus those who have attained Moksha), that number will be constant.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan- how and why do you think so? As bramhan is infinite it can create any number of atmans effortlessly and as he is governing body there is no need of making it constant.

Comment: @Yogi It's a well-established doctrine of the Brahma Sutras that it's impossible for new souls to ever be created.  Here's what Adi Shankaracharya says in his commentary on Adhyaya 2 Pada 2 Sutra 42 of the Brahma Sutras: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe34/sbe34218.htm "It is not possible ... for if such were the case, there would attach to the soul non-permanency, and all the other imperfections which belong to things originated. And thence release, which consists in reaching the highest Being, could not take place; for the effect is absorbed only by entering into its cause."

Comment: @Yogi See also Ramanujacharya's commentary on Adhyaya 2 Pada 3 Sutra 18 of the Brahma Sutras: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48264.htm In any case, the point is that souls are never created or destroyed.  Every Jivatma that currently exists has always existed, and it has taken infinitely many births going infinitely far back in time.

Comment: So why is there a goal for atman?? if ataman is truly infinite then it can be without goal or any support or association with bramhan

Comment: @Yogi I'm not sure what you mean by infinite.  Do you mean eternal?  In any case, yes the soul is eternal, but as long as it remains in the world of Samsara it suffers misery in birth after birth.  It's only by getting Moksha that it can achieve eternal happiness.  As Krishna says in the Bhagavad Gita, Brahman is the "dharma sukhasyaikantikasya" - the foundation of the only (true and lasting) happiness. http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/14/27

Comment: Apart from earth there is +7 and -7 energy plane called swarga and naraka. After death atma for a while be there before rebirth based on karma. Total no of atma is = All species life + diff life stage of soul in 14 energy plane which is constant at a given point. So, apparent +/- is not imp.

Comment: Let's assume there are finite Jeevas.. But since the Universe is from infinite time... There were infinite Brahmas... Moksha of Brahma is guranteed... it means there are infinite Jeevas who have attained Moksha... so if there was constant no. Of Jeevas then we wouldn't be here now... so there are Infinite Jeevas...

Comment: There is an infinite number which means that the number is constant. Infinite is Infinite. Constant.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda ok. Can you provide answer according to Vishishtadvaita that there are infinite no. of souls?

Comment: @Pandya, In advaita, Jiva (also known as ego or sookshma sharira) is the individual self , whereas the universal self is known by 3 names - Atman, Paramatma or Brahman. We jivas remain sentient  bcoz we dwell in the vast infinite feild of Atman/Brahman/Paramatma.

Comment: @Yogi, Yes, Atman is infinite. By infinite we mean endless, continuous, (the totality of everything that exists) ... For example, take a blank canvas. Think of it as Atman (also known as Brahman or Parmatma) ... Then draw a few galaxies, planets, living beings etc. in that blank canvas.  These galaxies, planets, stars, earth, moon, jivas etc. are all Atman's nama & rupa (material manifestations) which are  dwelling WITHIN the universal infinite field / canvas of Atman.

Comment: @Yogi, So what are the jivas then? Jivas are also material manifestations (rupas or forms) of Atman. Jiva literally means a living being. But in advaita, the word jiva is used for the transmigrating soul which is the sookshma sharira that houses the ego and intellect ..... (Jiva = Sookshma Sharira) ... So long story short, it is the goal of the jiva to attain liberation ... Upon liberation the sookshma sharira (jiva) stops existing, and then what remains? Only the infinite canvas called Atman remains.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one Atma from the standpoint of Atma. It is only through Maya, that the Atma, which is also called as Brahman, assumes various bodies and various forms. The jiva and the ishwara are both Atma itself that has become associated with different limiting principles called Upadhi.

Only from the standpoint of the world, there are innumerable number of jivas. From the standpoint of Brahman or Atman, Atman alone exist.

In Isha Upanishad (Verse 4), Atman is described as being "Ekam/One". In Aitereya Upanishad (1.1.1), it is said, "in the beginning, all these (the whole universe of multiplicity) was only Atman." Similarly, in Chandogya Upanishad (6.2.1), it is said: In begining, all this was non-dual Atman, the one without a second. Mandukya Upanishad describes Turiya (Atman) as being Advaitam/ Non-Dual. Non-dality means absence of two. Hence, Atman is one indivisible infinite whole.

Comment: Question is edited.

Comment: @NithnSridhar, Great answer buddy. Few ignorant ones use the word atman to address the individual self, thinking that each of us possess a distinct atman. But as per advaita, Atman is One. It is the totality of everything that exists. So the individual self should be the jiva and not Atman.