# Is creation cosmic injustice?

Tags: gods

God imposes bondage on us during creation deprive us from exalted state of consciousness. But we are supposed to put our own efforts to liberate. How is this justice? God puts veil of ignorance on us for his own selfishness of creation & we are the ones who supposed to liberate from these bondages? i.e, He is responsible for our bondages & we are supposed to be responsible for liberation. 
Isn't this cosmic injustice? If indeed it is (which seems to be), what is the justification of this injustice.?

Comment: jivAtmas never "entered" into Bondage during Creation, they have been in Samsara due to Karma Bandham without beginning in time. If anything Creation is God's mercy to give jivAtmas a chance at Moksha. I am assuming that by creation here you mean the creation of the universe.

Comment: The same is Shaiv Siddhanta view @LakshmiNarayanan but without beginning is unimaginable for me.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan I have asked this question here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18172/liberation-according-to-dual-or-semi-dual-schools-is-temporary

Comment: But this question is for all Indian philosophies.

Comment: This confusion is due to thinking that the association with one's Sarira is permanent. If we can cast away that illusion, we become more qualified to receive grace of SrimannArAyaNa

Comment: Nice question . logical and rational

Comment: If it is, it is an injustice the parabramham inflicted upon itself. For, it is the parabrahman that multiplied itself and set the creation process in motion including the 5 bhootas, 5 tanmatras, mano, buddhi, ahankara , chitta so on and so forth.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Good point. Very reasonable also. But why to inflict upon itself . Injustice to itself?

Comment: You make several a priori assumptions about creation and God's 'intentions' in your question that are misleading and fallacious. You have been unduly influenced by Christian thinking. I will be happy to give a response in the next day or two.

Comment: How this is duplicate? @TheDestroyer

Comment: @Fire. Did you click on big blue button "That Solved my Problem"?Btw, i won't get notified if you use " @ my name" as i didn't comment before here.

Answer (score 1):

> *"But we are supposed to put our own efforts to liberate. ... we are the ones who supposed to liberate from these bondages? ... we are supposed to be responsible for liberation."*

The central theme of this question is about "Why should **we** attempt for liberation, when we are being put into bondage by **someone else**".
IMO, this is already answered in following posts (hence duplicate):

- [Who gives Moksha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3563/1049)
- [Why doesn't Lord Krishna give Moksha to everyone?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13889/1049)

Another linked post: [Why does God allow us to suffer?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6855/1049)

Making it a community wiki straight away.

Comment: No, I am asking about justification of injustice. Swami Vishwananada ji told me to answer soon. This question might be super set of the links you have given .

Comment: @Fire., *"I am asking about justification of injustice"* -- The concern of supposed "injustice" is founded in an assumption that "we ourselves have to liberate". But as per linked posts, the liberation is not *achieved*, but *received* (or *attained* to be pedantic). Hence, the cause of creation itself is the cause of liberation. In other words, this is neither justice nor injustice, neither bondage nor liberate, neither this nor that, .. but beyond all.

Comment: C'mon we actually have to liberate. Saying indefinitely won't liberate us. Even if there is only assumption then also it is injustice as why we should remove this assumption when it was first initiated by him.

Answer (score 0):

I cant give any link to  back up my Answers. My knowledge is derived from multiple sources, mostly from Bhagavatam.Actual Answer is pretty vast.I will expand this answer , when I get time.

First of all , God **DOES NOT** imposes bondage on us. It is us , who left god . We fell down from our eternal place with god , because we wanted to go away from god. We didn't want to serve god. It is like parting from the god to set our own future. But since god is everywhere , there isn't any place , where there is no god.

So he changed some part of spiritual sky to become material sky(material universes) of lower vibration , in order to feel artificial separation. He created Maya to feel separateness.

Innumerable lokas(or universes) are like small cloud in the infinite spiritual sky. All stars , Galaxies and infinite cosmos which are visible with eyes or telescope is just small  fraction of material universes.

It is infact that , God asked us multiple times explaning what will happen if anyone left him. He warned that, our life would become difficult.But we forced him to let us go, inspite of the warnings.

We didnt believe in any of what he said.We set our own course and end up suffering. But God being very merciful , placed form of him in the heart of every soul in the form of paramatma(localized god) , as a key to return back , when we realized the mistake.

So one can use the key to go back to god , when we realized the mistake.

Comment: Thanks but Your answer indirectly implies enlightenment isn't permanent. Why in the first place enlightened beings fall?

Comment: There is always choice while being with god. God would NOT force anyone to be with him . So if someone wants to be De-Englightened while being enlightened , then he has choice

Comment: We all fell from enlightened state due to the Choice. As I have explained , , we chose the state because we wanted to go away from god. We didn't want to serve god. It is like parting from the god to set our own future. Go let us choose our own future