# as per different sects/philosophies, what was the order of creation/projection for ex: say- nirguna brahman-> aum-> ishwara -> maya-> ..... ->manu

Tags: sects, creation

Each sect have their own beleives about creation/projection.

Can we separately list as per each major/minor philosophies, **what was the order of creation/projection of say: "nirguna brahman, aum, ishwara , maya,Rtam,Dharma,brahma,jivatma,hiranya garbha, kaal(time), triguna(sat,rajas,tamas), earth,cosmic man(purusha)(as per rigveda's purush sukta),manu,sur(devas),asuras,......."** ?

---

**Just for example of what I am looking for** is something like below. Say, as per a 'hypothetical shaivite' named Sect1 creation order was as following:

- 1) Parashiva is nirguna brahman [Ref: ... Agama , Shloka ..]
- 2) He created Aum. [Ref: ..Veda , Shloka ..]
- 3) Then out of aum, "Shankara"(purusha) emerged. That is same as "Ishwara"(saguna brahman) and "Prakriti" also emerged [Ref: Agama named .., Shloka ..]
- 4) Shankara created vishnu [Shiva purana , Shloka ...]
- 5) from vishnu navel a lotus came out, from which brahma emerged
- 6) from prakriti, came out Parvati(consort of shiva), lakshmi(consort of vishnu came out).
- 7) from Brahma , saraswati came out
- 8) Vishnu created maya
- 9) In that maya , brahma created Rtam  and created hiranya garbha
- 10) from that hiraya garbha, all these stars and planets came out, including earth
- 11) from reflection of ishwara in maya , various jivatma appeared/projected
- 12) then brahma created triguna(sat,rajas,tamas)
- 12) brahma created Manu out of one of those jeevatma
- 13)  Then vishnu took form of cosmic man(purusha as per purusha sukta of rigveda) and then out of his head the brahmana emerged , from arms kshatriya emerged ,....  - from those earlier created jivatma.
- 14) Out of those Brahmanas, one sage was named Kashyapa . From Kashyapa and wife Aditi, the Suras came and from Kashyapa and Diti the Asuras came.

Now, as per "Hypothetical dvaitavaadi vaishnavite sect" named sect2, creation order is something like this:

.....

Now, as per "Hypothetical shakta sect" named sect3, creation order is something like this:
..

Now, as per "advaita vedanta" , projection order is something like this:
...

Now, as per "Smarta sect" named sect5, creation order is something like this:
...

Now, as per "sankhya" named sect6, creation order is something like this:
....

Now, as per "ISKCON krishnaite sect" named sect7, creation order is something like this:
....

Now, as per "tripurasundari(Shakta) sect" named sect8, creation order is something like this:
....

---

(note; I know that in above example of Sect1 creation hypothesis, I mish- mashed various sects philosophies in shiavite and other world view, but that was 'just an illustrative example' of what I am looking for..).

Comment: This needs to be reopened. This is a good Q and not too broad. Several scriptural works talk about the order of creation.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9291/do-shaivites-believe-in-something-greater-than-sadashiva/9452#9452

Comment: also see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19498/is-creation-cosmic-injustice