# Will the scriptural statements about continuous creation be falsified upon liberation of all as per Vaishnavism?

Tags: vaishnavism, mukti

According to Vaishnava Vedanta, this world is not the place to stay. And the real goal is to reach Vaikuntham. If all the jivas in the world attain mukti, then does the scripture statements about creation again after pralaya have any meaning. Is there any need for lord to create this world again? Or some new jivas are created to keep this world running?

Comment: See my comment to your same question about Advaita. It applies to this question also.

Comment: There are an infinite number of souls, so it's not possible for there to be a time when all Jivas have gotten moksha, yet it is still true that all Jivas will get moksha at one time. The process of creation will go on for infinity. There is no contradiction in this.

Comment: Its duplicate of [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18172/liberation-according-to-dual-dvait-or-semi-dual-vishishta-advait-schools-is)

Answer (score -1):

According to madhva tatva vada universe is created by aydhircha matra of lord i.e. gnana iccha to offer emancipation to mukthi yogi jivas. There is no falsification in this regard Jiva and paramatma is eternal, Jiva have swabhava associated with it.. some jivas who are not mukthi yogi will always be in the cycle according to atma swabhava.. some jivas will go to andhamas BG 16.16-20. so god will be having plenty jiva for creation.Tattvavada is the only religion which explains creation, sustenance and dissloution according to BG, Vedas correctly. If Jiva is pure and it is only one as stated by Advaita why it had manifested in different consciousness initially why it got multiplied Jiva is Sanatana and so do pramatma. If you accept Advaita  you need attribute dhosa to lord for creating this universe this cannot be case.