# regarding some questions on souls

Tags: atma

I heard that souls( atma) never born, never died. Its target is unity with paramatma and atma accomplished  this through different births. My question: Since total population is increasing then from where the extra souls are coming? Actually number of souls should decresing as some souls attain the unity. Then we arrive at a contradiction...
If the 1st line of my question is false then tell me the truth about souls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3733/are-new-souls-created

Comment: if you only look at the earth and only humans, then yeah population is increasing.. but there are fewer animals now, so where did those animal souls go ? and there are so many planets and lokas in the universe, did you look at population in those too ? maybe it is decreasing :).. actually no, it is neither increasing nor decreasing.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59501/discussion-on-question-by-santanu-debnath-regarding-some-questions-on-souls).

Comment: Related: [No. of souls](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8443/277)