# Which scriptures talk about Kalachakra?

Tags: time, chakras

We have the concept of Kala Chakra (wheel of time) in both Buddhism and Hinduism.  Which scriptures talk about Kalachakra?

Comment: The answer to your Qn also exists here: [When Brahma's day ends and a new day starts does the previous day repeat itself?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20415/1049). However there can be other scriptures too, who would be discussing *"Kala chakra"*, which scientists may also refer as [Cyclic model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_model).

Answer (score 2):

**Bhagavad Gita talks about *KAlachakra***. In English it can also be interpreted as [Eternal Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_return#Indian_religions). The etymology is as:

> *KAla* = time, *Chakra* = cycle (i.e. duration)

The time passes in a circular motion. In a given cycle, all the unique events will happen once. In the next/past cycles (frequency), the same events only occur.
e.g. You will be asking this Qn in every cycle and I will be answering them. Same is true for all the events of your/mine/others' lives.

> BG 8.17 - Knowing that thousand eras constitute a day of Brahman, [and] thousand eras complete a night, are the people who know day, [and] night.
>   BG 8.18 - On arrival of day, all manifestations originate from "Unmanifest"; On arrival of night they annihilate into [what is] known as "Unmanifest" only.
>   BG 8.19 - **This world of beings only happens again & again**; Annihilates upon arrival of night, [and] originates upon arrival of day.
>   BG 9.10 - Under "My" supervision, the *Prakruti* produces moving & non-moving [beings]; **Due to this reason the world revolves**

Comment: KAl chakra is also very deep concept. The great Gautam Buddha taught on request to the king of Salivahan (mystical city where Kalki will born)