# Does Bhagavad Gita state that "... Atmaa discards old bodies and assumes new bodies"?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, identification-request, atma

While watching a famous hit Hindi movie [Kudarat (1981)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kudrat), I came across a place where the protagonist states below in a court:

> > *"In Gita, the blessed lord has told that, how human throws away old cloths and wears new cloths, similarly **Atmaa** also leaves an old body and assumes a new body"*

Here is a [video link](https://youtu.be/XJs3l2Sre9M?t=8377) to the dialog.

Is any such verse existing in Bhagavad Gita?

Comment: If you are going to close as duplicate, why did you ask and why did you answer?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, the other post is closed as too broad, hence I can't add a dedicated answer there. This is the only way. If you feel that this answer belong there, then help reopen that post. Also refer meta post [A question related to "Wrong attribution to Bhagavad Gita", should be kept open](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1152/1049) for more details.

Comment: This time they showed it correctly :D @iammilind

Comment: @Rickross, Yes - so the answer is also on the same theme. I mentioned as a "*slight error*". However, the word *Atmaa* (not *Atma*) used in that dialog doesn't match the translation. Because, the original word *Dehi* (embodied) can be anything, like *Mann*, *Buddhi*, *Purusha*. The word *Atma* is separately used in different context throughout Gita. So even though the error is slight, the meaning differs. This is a slight deviation and not a major one.

Comment: @iammilind No IMO ur answer seems to be "No such verses found.." but actually it shd be "Yes there is a verse.. "... See Grihi means "one who lives in the Griha (house)" or "one who owns it".. Similarly Dehi means "one who lives in the Deha (body) or who owns it".. So, Dehi is infact the soul/Jiva here.. That's why upvoted only the Q and not the A.

Comment: @Rickross, You say dehi means, one who lives in the body. But then one would ask, in which body? ... The physical, subtle or the causal?

Comment: No need to complicate things.. it's the soul which lives in the body and it is the owner of the body too .. here body (Linga Deha) can mean all the 3 bodies u have mentioned.. so Dehi is referring to the soul/Jiva only. @TheCrimsonUniverse

Comment: First of all Atman and soul are not the same thing , as per Advaita atleast. According to them, Atman is all pervasive (present everywhere). Since it is present everywhere, it has no reason to move from one gross body to another gross body. So then who does? They say, it's the soul or jiva. They explain this soul/jiva to be the subtle body which is itself inert/jada but made conscious with the rays or reflection of Atman. So according to the advaita, dehi is the ""sookshma sharira AKA soul AKA jiva"" that inhabits or resides within the deha called gross body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there is a very similar verse in Bhagavad Gita, there is no reference of *Atmaa* in that. Probably the translation of Prabhupada (ISKCON), which is quite famous, could be source of that *slight error*.

> BG 2.22 - As a person puts on new garments, giving up old ones, **the soul** similarly accepts new material bodies, giving up the old and useless ones.

Most of the people translate "soul = *Atmaa*". And this could be the reason of such misconception.
[There is NO reference of "soul" in the actual Bhagavad Gita translations](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26795/1049)

Here is the more accurate translation from Gambhirananda:

> BG 2.22 - As after rejecting worn out clothes a man takes up other new ones, likewise after rejecting worn out bodies the '**embodied one**' unites with other new ones.

In the original verse, the word is ***Dehi (देही)*** and Not *Atma*.
This could also be the reason, why people in popular culture (such as movies), refer the term as *"My soul (Atma) and your soul (Atma) are one"* etc..

Comment: You do realize the "embodied one" is another term for the Jiva or soul.